# Update twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I have a rails project with twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and twitter bootstrap 2. Now I need to migrate to twitter bootstrap 3. But I don't know how to do this, because I update my gemfile like this:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

and everything works perfect, so I guess nothing is updated. How I can update my gem and work with twitter bootstrap 3.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `bundle update twitter-bootstrap-rails`

Comment: I tried but everything is the same, how to I know if now I can use twitter bootstrap syntax???

Comment: In dev mode, do a `view source` on any `HTML` page and click on the bootstrap css file. It will show you the version on top.

Comment: No :( I have the same version 2.3.2

Comment: since you are switching from bootstrap 2 to bootstrap 3 then why don't you use bootstraps official gem [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) you need to switch to the **bootstrap3** branch, so add a `branch` option to your Gemfile.

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :github => 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails', :branch => 'bootstrap3'
```

Comment: Also consider using the actual official bootstrap-sass release. I'm not sure what if anything twitter-bootstrap-rails has over it. The official bootstrap-sass gem pretty much just works with Rails 3+, and the README says so. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass  I think twitter-bootstrap-rails may have been created before there was an official bootstrap-sass.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation of the gem here: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/tree/bootstrap3

Try generating the assets using the described procedure based on whether you are using less or static css.